# TweenLite animation does not work with no errors

Tags: javascript, html, animation, web, gsap

I tried to use TweenLite to animate some elements, but it didn't work !
The console.log command works, no errors occures, but nothing happens too.

This is the script :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var back = document.getElementById("back");
        var table = document.getElementById("table");

        console.log(table);
        //TweenLite.to(table,4,{top:"4500px" , height:"0px"});
        TweenLite.to(table,4,{top:"4500"});
        TweenLite.to(back, 1.5, {width:100});
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to animate CSS properties with **[TweenLite](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/)** JS script, You will need to include the GSAP **[CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)** separately.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

If you ONLY include the [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) JS script, then you don't have to include the [CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/) since it is included in [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) for convenience.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

**[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/)** includes the following:

- CSSPlugin
- RoundPropsPlugin
- BezierPlugin
- AttrPlugin
- DirectionalRotationPlugin
- EasePack
- TimelineLite
- TimelineMax

Hope this helps! :)